# Grouping categorical data over other categorical data with python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas, grouping, cluster-computing

I have a pandas dataframe with a column that stores the name of particular task and another column reporting the id number of the employee who performed that task. Something similar to:

```
EMPLOYEE_ID    TASK_NAME 

Employee1     Inspection  
Employee2     Inspection
Employee3     Inspection
Employee4     Inspection
Employee5     Inspection
Employee1     Change
Employee2     Inspection
Employee3     Change
Employee1     Change
Employee2     Change
```

I was wondering what type of command/analyses I have to do in order to group/cluster employees over task performed. In other words, I'd like to to say that, for instance, "Employee_Group_1" (which includes Employee1, Employee2, Employee3) has performed 75% of all Inspection and Change tasks..

Any help would be much apprecieated!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am confused on exactly what you are asking.  Can you rephrase and add expected output from this given data.

Comment: IIUC, you can create a column assigning each employee ID to an employee group, and then use `groupby` to do some summary statistics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe need [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by flattened `dictionary` called `d1` with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
d = {'g1':['Employee1', 'Employee2', 'Employee3'],
     'g2':['Employee4', 'Employee5', 'Employee6']}

d1 = {k: oldk for oldk, oldv in d.items() for k in oldv}
print (d1)
{'Employee1': 'g1', 'Employee2': 'g1', 'Employee3': 'g1', 
 'Employee4': 'g2', 'Employee5': 'g2', 'Employee6': 'g2'}

s = df['EMPLOYEE_ID'].map(d1).value_counts(normalize=True)
print (s)
g1    0.8
g2    0.2
Name: EMPLOYEE_ID, dtype: float64
```

If want also analyze another column use [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html):

```
df2 = (df.groupby(df['EMPLOYEE_ID'].map(d1))['TASK_NAME']
         .value_counts(normalize=True)
         .reset_index(name='norm'))
print (df2)
  EMPLOYEE_ID   TASK_NAME  norm
0          g1      Change   0.5
1          g1  Inspection   0.5
2          g2  Inspection   1.0
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df['EMPLOYEE_ID'].map(d1))
0    g1
1    g1
2    g1
3    g2
4    g2
5    g1
6    g1
7    g1
8    g1
9    g1
Name: EMPLOYEE_ID, dtype: object
```